# Given a type, search for an item of that type in a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, template

In my project, I want to search for an item of a given type in a `std::tuple` at compile time. The given type might not be present in the tuple at all, in which case some invalid value should be returned to signal that. I'm using c++17 by the way.

```cpp
template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct contains {
    static constexpr bool value = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Arg, Args>...>;
};
template<typename... Args>
struct Stuffs {
    std::tuple<Args...> data;

    template<typename Arg>
    std::enable_if_t<contains<Arg, Args...>::value, Arg*>
    constexpr search() {
        auto& ref = std::get<Arg>(data);
        return &ref;
    }
    template<typename Arg>
    std::enable_if_t<!contains<Arg, Args...>::value, Arg*>
    constexpr search() {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    struct A { int val = 100; };
    struct B {};
    struct C {};
    struct D {};
    struct E {};

    if constexpr (Stuffs<A, B, C, D>{}.search<A>()->val == 100) {
        std::cout << "A found" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr (Stuffs<A, B, C, D>{}.search<E>()) {
        std::cout << "should not happen" << std::endl;
    }
    if constexpr (Stuffs<A, B, C, D>{}.search<int>()) {
        std::cout << "should not happen" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code seems to work fine in terms of searching in a tuple at compile time. Initially, I tried to use `std::variant` and `void*` but their operations are mostly prohibited in a `constexpr` setting. Then I arrived at this approach.  I'm new to C++ template programming, so I'm wondering if there are any potential issues with this code and how I may improve it?

Comment: I mean… *technically* you are allowed to put the declaration specifiers in any order… but I’ve never seen anyone put the `constexpr` after the return type unless they were being deliberately silly. 

Comment: @indi I felt it was more readable than `constexpr enable_if_t <...>`

Comment: I’m very wary of claims that code is more “readable” when it violates universal conventions. Put another way: more readable… for *whom*? Someone who doesn’t really *know* C++? Or someone who knows it very well? Consider: I have been C++ing since before the first standard, and read/write both beginner and advanced C++ code roughly every day… and *I* was flummoxed for a minute, had to stop and remember the grammar rules and reason it through, before I could accept it. Programming is communication; speaking in strange ways, even if it makes more sense to *you*, is communicating poorly.

Comment: I’d also add that if you used more modern C++ features, your readability problem goes away. For example, with trailing return syntax (which is superior in almost every way) and C++20 `requires` (which makes `enable_if` obsolete), you could do: `template <typename Arg>⏎requires contains<Arg, Args...>::value⏎constexpr auto search() -> Arg*`. There are no **rules**, of course, so if you prefer your way, stick with it. As long as you’re consistent within a particular codebase, it’s fine.

Comment: @indi well said, I appreciate your insights and great response. I'll keep this in mind when writing code in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great idea, and is pretty well-done. Not bad for someone new to metaprogramming!

I have only two major suggestions for improving `contains`.

The first is to either have it inherit from `std::bool_constant`, or to-reimplement all the stuff in `bool_constant`.

That’s because `bool_constant` is more than just its `value`. There are other handy conversions baked in. This is (roughly) what bool constant looks like:

```
template <bool V>
struct bool_constant
{
    using type       = bool_constant;
    using value_type = bool;

    static constexpr bool value = V;

    constexpr auto operator()() const noexcept { return V; }

    constexpr operator auto() const noexcept { return V; }
};
```

You’ve got the `value`, but none of the other features. They are not often used, sure, but since you get them for free, you might as well do:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct contains 
    : std::bool_constant<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Arg, Args>...>>
{};
```

You could also do:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct contains 
    : std::disjunction<std::is_same<Arg, Args>...>
{};
```

But I don’t recommend that, because a `std::disjunction` can boil down to a random type that may not support the full interface. And the whole point is you want the full interface.

The second major suggestion is to change the interface slightly to make it easier to use.

What I would like to do is write:

```
using my_tuple = std::tuple<int, float, std::string>

if (contains<my_tuple, int>::value)
    // ...

// Or:
if (contains<std::tuple<int, float, std::string>, int>::value)
    // ...
```

But I can’t write that. In fact, I can’t use `contains` at all without additional boilerplate to hoist the tuple’s types out of the tuple. `contains` itself is like three lines, but you need more than double that (in the `Stuffs` class) to be able to actually *use* it meaningfully.

What you should do is use partial specialization to extract the types automatically, like so:

```
// Primary template. Leave undefined, so it only works with tuples or
// tuple-like stuff.
template <typename Haystack, typename Needle>
struct contains;

// Specialization for std::tuple:
template <typename Needle, typename... Args>
struct contains<std::tuple<Args...>, Needle>
    : std::bool_constant<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Needle, Args>...>>
{};

// Or,  better: specialization for any kind of type list or anything tuple-like:
template <template <typename...> typename Haystack, typename Needle, typename... Args>
struct contains<Haystack<Args...>, Needle>
    : std::bool_constant<std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Needle, Args>...>>
{};
```

Now you no longer need `Stuffs` to use the `contains` metafunction… though you could still do it if you want:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Stuffs
{
    std::tuple<Args...> data;

    // Don't really need enable_if for this.
    template <typename Arg>
    constexpr auto search() -> Arg*
    {
        if constexpr (contains<std::tuple<Args...>, Arg>::value)
            return &std::get<Arg>(data);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Now, all that being said, I suggest that you may have solved the wrong problem.

If *all you want* is to test whether some type is in a tuple, then fine, nailed it.

*However*… ***is that all you want***?

Because even in your sample code, you want more. You not only want to know whether a type is in a tuple… *you want to access that type*.

And since you want that, you end up doing the work twice. First you search the tuple to find the type. Then you search it again (via `std::get<Arg>()`) to *get* the type. That’s a waste of effort. You already found it… why forget about it then search for it again?

You may argue that the efficiency waste doesn’t matter, because all this is happening at compile time, and that is true. However, there is another problem. Try [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/zThqEbhYv):

```
auto main() -> int
{
    if (Stuffs<int, int>{}.search<int>() != nullptr)
        std::cout << "found!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "not found\n";
}
```

The problem isn’t your code, it’s `std::get<T>()`. That fails if you use a type that exists more than once in the tuple. You know there’s in an `int` in there… but you can’t access it.

So I would suggest that the problem that you really want to solve is not *whether* `Arg` is in `tuple<Args...>`, but *where* `Arg` is in `tuple<Args...>`.

So instead of just a `contains` function which returns a `bool`, what you actually want is a `find` function that returns an *index*.

Suppose you did have this `find` metafunction:

```
template <typename Haystack, typename Needle>
struct find;

// Returns the index of the first occurence of Needle, or size_t{-1}.
template <template <typename...> typename Haystack, typename Needle, typename... Args>
struct find<Haystack<Args...>, Needle>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, /* magic! */>
{};
```

Now your `Stuffs` operation becomes:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Stuffs
{
    std::tuple<Args...> data;

    // Don't really need enable_if for this.
    template <typename Arg>
    constexpr auto search() -> Arg*
    {
        constexpr auto index = find<tuple<Args...>, Arg>::value;

        if constexpr (index != std::size_t{-1})
            return &std::get<index>(data);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
};
```

And this will always work, even for tuples with duplicate types. And you’re only searching the tuple once.

In fact, the `find` operation is fundamental, so you can even write `contains` in terms of it:

```
template <typename Haystack, typename Needle>
struct contains
    : std::bool_constant<find<Haystack, Needle>::value != std::size_t{-1}>
{};
```

In *fact*, you could go even further, and have a metafunction `find_all` that returns a `std::index_sequence` with the indices of every occurrence of a needle. So:

```
find_all<tuple<int, float, char, int, int, double, int>, int>
// value_type is index_sequence<0, 3, 4, 6>

find_all<tuple<int, float, char, int, int, double, int>, double>
// value_type is index_sequence<5>

find_all<tuple<int, float, char, int, int, double, int>, short>
// value_type is index_sequence<>
```

And then make `find` in terms of that (whenever the length of the index sequence is non-zero, take the first index). And `contains` would still be in terms of `find`. *Plus* you could also write another metafunction `count` that counts the number of times a type is in a tuple… that could be in terms of `find_all` too. **Plus** you could easily write a `find_last`. And a `unique`. And so on.

Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

An interesting question, and already an excellent answer by indi. I just want to add:

## Make it a `get_if<>()` for tuples

For `std::variant` they made a [`std::get_if<>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) function that is basically what you want, except it doesn't work for tuples. However, you could modify your code to do that:

```
template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct contains {
    static constexpr bool value = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<Arg, Args>...>;
};

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<contains<Arg, Args...>::value, Arg*>
constexpr get_if(std::tuple<Args...>&& tuple) {
    return &std::get<Arg>(tuple);    
}

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
Arg*
constexpr get_if(std::tuple<Args...>&& tuple) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
struct A { int val = 100; };
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};
struct E {};

using Stuffs = std::tuple<A, B, C, D>;

if constexpr (get_if<A>(Stuffs{})->val == 100)
    std::cout << "A found\n";
if constexpr (get_if<E>(Stuffs{}))
    std::cout << "should not happen\n";
if constexpr (get_if<int>(Stuffs{}))
    std::cout << "should not happen\n";
```

Just like indi's `contains` and `find()`, it's now a free function that works on regular `std::tuple`s, no need to write a wrapper class.

It still has the issue that it doesn't handle tuples with duplicate types, but then again, `std::get_if()` for `std::variant`s doesn't handle that case either, so there is at least no surprising behavior here.

Note that tuples might be passed as `const` and non-`const` lvalue references and as rvalues, the above code doesn't handle all cases. This is left as an excercise for the reader.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not nececssary and negatively impacts performance.